# How to make tab position below action bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have a main tab activity where i have two tabs, the tab position are below the layout, I want the tab positions below the actionbar like in google play and when i move from one tab to another tab, the data shows from previous tab even though i set saveEnabled to false.
Here is my code

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab


    // Do the same for the other tabs

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, RunningOrder.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("runningOrder")
    .setIndicator("Running Order",   res.getDrawable(R.drawable.running_order))
        .setIndicator("Running Order")
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, OrderHistoryTab.class);
    spec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("orderHistory")
    .setIndicator("Order History",
    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.history_icon))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //set tab which one you want open first time 0 or 1 or 2
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

And this is my xml layout

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



  <TabHost
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:saveEnabled="false"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  >

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for making tab position below of the action bar swap frameLayout and tabWidget position.

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: and why does in current tab it shows the previous tab data

Answer (score 0):

To achieve like Google Play you can use TabLayout along with viewpager from design support library.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/hometoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/app_action_bar_primary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hometoolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_color_secondary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/home_tab_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your Activity you can code as below,

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Running Order"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Order History"));
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
         (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can create Adapter by extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter as below,

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs;
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    RunningOrderFragment tab1 = new RunningOrderFragment();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    OrderHistoryFragment tab2 = new OrderHistoryFragment();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.